# replace() on variable not working

Tags: javascript, replace, immutability

replace() is not working on a variable I've created representative of a bunch of names I'm deriving from a JSON object in a loop.

I understand strings are immutable in JS. I believe I have ruled that out.

```
for (object in Object.keys(json)) {
    console.log(json[object]["senderProfile"]["name"])
    var name_ = String(json[object]["senderProfile"]["name"])
    var name = name_.replace(',', '')
    names.push(name+"<br>")
}

document.getElementById("json_out").innerHTML = names;
```

The HTML that is rendered has commas in between each name. Not sure what to make of it.

Comment: Try this: `document.getElementById("json_out").innerHTML = names.join("");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`names` is an array. You are implicitly converting the array to a string. By default, array members are separated by comma. Simple example:

```js
console.log('' + [1,2,3])
```

You can join array members with a custom separator by calling [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
console.log('' + [1,2,3].join(''))
```

---

It may be possible to simplify your code, but not without knowing what the value of `json` or `json[object]["senderProfile"]["name"]` is. However, instead of appending `<br>` to the name, you could use it as the element separator:

```
var names = Object.keys(json)
  .map(key => json[key]["senderProfile"]["name"]);

document.getElementById("json_out").innerHTML = names.join('<br>');
```

Comment: Gah I knew it had to do with the array structure. Thank you. Rusty on my JS fundamentals ;) I will answer ASAP.